# How can I use XOR mode when calling DrawRectangle method in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, paint, xor

As the title says, I want to paint something with XOR mode because I want to clean it after a period of time.

I'm using C# (Window Form) with Visual Studio 2010.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: XOR operations were completely removed from GDI+.  There's one back-door left: ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a nice extension for .net:

```
public static class XorDrawing
{

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetROP2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private extern static int SetROP2(IntPtr hdc, int fnDrawMode);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "MoveToEx", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private extern static bool MoveToEx(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y, IntPtr lpPoint);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "LineTo", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private extern static bool LineTo(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SelectObject")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject([In] IntPtr hdc, [In] IntPtr hgdiobj);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr target);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreatePen(PenStyle fnPenStyle, int nWidth, uint crColor);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWorldTransform(IntPtr hdc, [In] ref XFORM lpXform);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetGraphicsMode(IntPtr hdc, int iMode);

    /// <summary>
    ///   The XFORM structure specifies a world-space to page-space transformation.
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct XFORM
    {
        public float eM11;
        public float eM12;
        public float eM21;
        public float eM22;
        public float eDx;
        public float eDy;

        public XFORM(float eM11, float eM12, float eM21, float eM22, float eDx, float eDy)
        {
            this.eM11 = eM11;
            this.eM12 = eM12;
            this.eM21 = eM21;
            this.eM22 = eM22;
            this.eDx = eDx;
            this.eDy = eDy;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Allows implicit converstion to a managed transformation matrix.
        /// </summary>
        public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix(XFORM xf)
        {
            return new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix(xf.eM11, xf.eM12, xf.eM21, xf.eM22, xf.eDx, xf.eDy);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Allows implicit converstion from a managed transformation matrix.
        /// </summary>
        public static implicit operator XFORM(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix m)
        {
            float[] elems = m.Elements;
            return new XFORM(elems[0], elems[1], elems[2], elems[3], elems[4], elems[5]);
        }
    }

    public enum BinaryRasterOperations
    {
        R2_BLACK = 1,
        R2_NOTMERGEPEN = 2,
        R2_MASKNOTPEN = 3,
        R2_NOTCOPYPEN = 4,
        R2_MASKPENNOT = 5,
        R2_NOT = 6,
        R2_XORPEN = 7,
        R2_NOTMASKPEN = 8,
        R2_MASKPEN = 9,
        R2_NOTXORPEN = 10,
        R2_NOP = 11,
        R2_MERGENOTPEN = 12,
        R2_COPYPEN = 13,
        R2_MERGEPENNOT = 14,
        R2_MERGEPEN = 15,
        R2_WHITE = 16
    }

    private enum PenStyle : int
    {
        PS_SOLID = 0, //The pen is solid.
        PS_DASH = 1, //The pen is dashed.
        PS_DOT = 2, //The pen is dotted.
        PS_DASHDOT = 3, //The pen has alternating dashes and dots.
        PS_DASHDOTDOT = 4, //The pen has alternating dashes and double dots.
        PS_NULL = 5, //The pen is invisible.
        PS_INSIDEFRAME = 6,// Normally when the edge is drawn, it’s centred on the outer edge meaning that half the width of the pen is drawn
        // outside the shape’s edge, half is inside the shape’s edge. When PS_INSIDEFRAME is specified the edge is drawn 
        //completely inside the outer edge of the shape.
        PS_USERSTYLE = 7,
        PS_ALTERNATE = 8,
        PS_STYLE_MASK = 0x0000000F,

        PS_ENDCAP_ROUND = 0x00000000,
        PS_ENDCAP_SQUARE = 0x00000100,
        PS_ENDCAP_FLAT = 0x00000200,
        PS_ENDCAP_MASK = 0x00000F00,

        PS_JOIN_ROUND = 0x00000000,
        PS_JOIN_BEVEL = 0x00001000,
        PS_JOIN_MITER = 0x00002000,
        PS_JOIN_MASK = 0x0000F000,

        PS_COSMETIC = 0x00000000,
        PS_GEOMETRIC = 0x00010000,
        PS_TYPE_MASK = 0x000F0000
    };

    public enum GraphicsMode : int
    {   
        GM_COMPATIBLE = 1,
        GM_ADVANCED = 2,
    }

    private static IntPtr BeginDraw(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, bool dash, out int oldRop, out IntPtr img, out IntPtr oldpen)
    {
        var gHdc = graphics.GetHdc();
        var hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(gHdc);
        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);

        img = bmp.GetHbitmap();
        SelectObject(hdc, img);

        oldpen = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (dash)
        {
            var pen = CreatePen(PenStyle.PS_DASH, 1, 0);
            oldpen = SelectObject(hdc, pen);
        }
        oldRop = SetROP2(hdc, (int)BinaryRasterOperations.R2_NOTXORPEN); // Switch to inverted mode. (XOR)

        SetGraphicsMode(hdc, (int)GraphicsMode.GM_ADVANCED);
        XFORM transform = graphics.Transform;
        SetWorldTransform(hdc, ref transform);

        return hdc;
    }


    private static void FinishDraw(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, IntPtr hdc, IntPtr oldpen, int oldRop, IntPtr img, bool dash)
    {
        SetROP2(hdc, oldRop);

        var transform = graphics.Transform;
        graphics.ResetTransform(); //in case there is transform
        var outBmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(img);
        //CopyChannel(bmp, outBmp, ChannelARGB.Alpha, ChannelARGB.Alpha);
        graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        graphics.DrawImage(outBmp, 0, 0); //draw the xored image on the bitmap
        graphics.Transform = transform;

        if (dash) DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, oldpen)); //delete new pen (switch to oldpen)
        DeleteObject(img); // Delete the GDI bitmap (important).
        DeleteObject(hdc);
    }

    public static void DrawXorLine(this System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, bool dash = true)
    {
        int oldRop;
        IntPtr oldpen, img;
        var hdc = BeginDraw(bmp, graphics, x1, y1, x2, y2, dash, out oldRop, out img, out oldpen);

        MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, IntPtr.Zero);
        LineTo(hdc, x2, y2);

        FinishDraw(bmp, graphics, hdc, oldpen, oldRop, img, dash);
    }

    public static void DrawXorRectangle(this System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, bool dash = true)
    {
        int oldRop;
        IntPtr oldpen, img;
        var hdc = BeginDraw(bmp, graphics, x1, y1, x2, y2, dash, out oldRop, out img, out oldpen);

        MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, IntPtr.Zero); //clockwise
        LineTo(hdc, x2, y1);
        LineTo(hdc, x2, y2);
        LineTo(hdc, x1, y2);
        LineTo(hdc, x1, y1);

        FinishDraw(bmp, graphics, hdc, oldpen, oldRop, img, dash);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
g.DrawXorRectangle(bmp, outRect.Left, outRect.Top, outRect.Left + outRect.Width, outRect.Top + outRect.Height);
```

Or

```
g.DrawXorLine(bmp, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Windows API functions. I wrapped the imports in the static class `Win32`.

```
public static class Win32
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetROP2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public extern static int SetROP2(IntPtr hdc, int fnDrawMode);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public extern static IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ReleaseDC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public extern static IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "MoveToEx", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public extern static bool MoveToEx(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y, IntPtr lpPoint);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "LineTo", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public extern static bool LineTo(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y);

    public const int R2_NOT = 6;  // Inverted drawing mode

}
```

Using these definitions you can draw like this

```
IntPtr hdc = Win32.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero); // Get device context.
Win32.SetROP2(hdc, Win32.R2_NOT); // Switch to inverted mode. (XOR)
Win32.MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, IntPtr.Zero);
Win32.LineTo(hdc, x2, y2);
Win32.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc); // Release device context.
```

Note that the standard drawing functions provided by .NET through the `Graphics` object do not work in inverted mode. You must use the functions of the API, shown here with `MoveToEx` and `LineTo` as an example.

---

I extracted these examples from my Code Project article [Drag-and-Drop ListBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36412/Drag-and-Drop-ListBox).

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific about what you are using, but I am assuming GDI+ and Windows Forms.

```
Region region = new Region();
region.MakeEmpty();
region.Xor(rectangle1);
region.Xor(rectangle2);
e.Graphics.FillRegion(Brushes.Black, region); // use e.Graphics if in Paint event
```

Comment: Hello, I'm using Window Forms. I have overrided the OnPaint method of class PictureBox to paint a Rectangle

Comment: This creates a Region and has nothing to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: yes it does.  He's specifically giving an answer that meets the needs.  The OP wanted a rectangle to be drawn in XOR mode in GDI.  That's exactly what it is.

Comment: no my friends, he wanted something what DrawFocusRect function does. He is very clear about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawfocusrect

Comment: So maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawfocusrect  will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper class for the gdi32.dll.
/// </summary>
public class Gdi32
{
    public enum DrawingMode
    {
        R2_NOTXORPEN = 10
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool Rectangle(IntPtr hDC, int left, int top, int right, int bottom);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetROP2(IntPtr hDC, int fnDrawMode);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool MoveToEx(IntPtr hDC, int x, int y, ref Point p);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool LineTo(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreatePen(int fnPenStyle, int nWidth, int crColor);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObj);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObj);

}

/// <summary>
/// Provides utilities directly accessing the gdi32.dll 
/// </summary>
public class GDI
{
    static private Point nullPoint = new Point(0,0);

    // Convert the Argb from .NET to a gdi32 RGB
    static private int ArgbToRGB(int rgb)
    {
        return ((rgb >> 16 & 0x0000FF)| (rgb & 0x00FF00) | (rgb << 16 & 0xFF0000));
    }
    static public void DrawXORRectangle(Graphics graphics, Pen pen, Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr hPen = Gdi32.CreatePen(0, (int)pen.Width, ArgbToRGB(pen.Color.ToArgb()));
        Gdi32.SelectObject(hDC, hPen);
        Gdi32.SetROP2(hDC, (int)Gdi32.DrawingMode.R2_NOTXORPEN);
        Gdi32.Rectangle(hDC, rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Right,rectangle.Bottom);
        Gdi32.DeleteObject(hPen);
        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
    }

    static public void DrawXORLine(Graphics graphics, Pen pen, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr hPen = Gdi32.CreatePen(0, (int)pen.Width, ArgbToRGB(pen.Color.ToArgb()));
        Gdi32.SelectObject(hDC, hPen);
        Gdi32.SetROP2(hDC, (int)Gdi32.DrawingMode.R2_NOTXORPEN);
        Gdi32.MoveToEx(hDC, x1, y1, ref nullPoint);
        Gdi32.LineTo(hDC, x2, y2);
        Gdi32.DeleteObject(hPen);
        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
    }
}
```